# Create a main program with two tabs from two different JFrame classes

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jframe

I would like to know how it is possible to write a main program in java with two tabs (probably with using JTabbedPane) using two different classes that extend JFrame. The two other classes work and run fine as independent programs, having their own menus (JMenu) etc. but I want each one of them to be a tab to the main program. The main program that I wrote is this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class mainApp {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
ServicesTab tab1 = new ServicesTab();
ContractsTab tab2 = new ContractsTab();

public mainApp() {
    tabbedPane.add("Services", tab1);
    tabbedPane.add("Contracts", tab2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350, 150);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new mainApp();
        }
    });
}
}
```

but when I run it, it only opens the two tabs (classes) as two seperate programs.

Comment: Both ServicesTab and ContractsTab should not extend JFrame but rather JPanel. You are painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

Comment: Ok, so I write the two classes that I want to use as JPanel, removing the menu and adding it to the JFrame main class. Now, how am I going to add the as tabs in the main program?

Comment: As you would any other JPanel that you add to a JTabbedPane. Please clarify the problem you're having.

Comment: I have tried different ways but still I can't make it. I just want to show me the code in order to get it done, please.

Comment: Since none of us know what problems you are having with your attempt, **no one can "show you the code"**. Please ask a new question, one that shows your [mcve] / [sscce](http://sscce.org) attempt, one with clear detail on what errors or problems you are having. Let's avoid discussion of vague undefined problems or "not working" and instead work with a clear cut well-defined problem and decent code.